# Issue with column command and color escape codes

Tags: colors, escape-characters, columns, text-formatting, table

I'm colorizing the header of a table formatted with `column -ts $'\t'`

Works well without color codes, but when I add color codes to the first line `column` doesn't properly align the output.

Without colored output it works **as expected**:
`printf "1\t2\t3\nasdasdasdasdasdasdasd\tqwe\tqweqwe\n" | column -ts $'\t'`

But when adding color on the first line column **doesn't align** the text of the colored row:
`printf "\e[7m1\t2\t3\e[0m\nasdasdasdasdasdasdasd\tqwe\tqweqwe\n" | column -ts $'\t'`

Observed this behaviour both on Ubuntu Linux and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that `column` doesn't know that `\e[7m` is a v100 escape sequence that takes no space in the output. It seems to asssume character codes 0 to 037 octal take no space. You can get what you want by putting the initial escape sequence on a line of its own, then removing that newline from the output:

```
printf '\e[7m\n1\t2\t3\e[0m\nasdasdasdasdasdasdasd\tqwe\tqweqwe\n' | 
column -ts $'\t' |
sed '1{N;s/\n//}'
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right. Also using colors in some columns of other rows where this newline workaround won't work, but I'll work around that with the method @terdon suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's because the color codes are also being formatted by `column`. They are characters just like any other. Since you're already using `printf` though, you may as well use it to do the formatting for you:

```
$ printf '\e[7m%-24s%-8s%-6s\e[0m\n%-24s%-8s%-6s\n' "1" "2" "3" "asdasdasdasdasdasdasd" "qwe" "qweqwe"
1                       2       3     
asdasdasdasdasdasdasd   qwe     qweqwe
```

Alternatively, you can add the color codes *after* using `column`:

```
$ printf "1\t2\t3\nasdasdasdasdasdasdasd\tqwe\tqweqwe\n" | column -ts $'\t' | 
    sed "1{s/^/$(printf '\e[7m')/;s/$/$(printf '\e[0m')/}"
1                      2    3   # this line is colored
asdasdasdasdasdasdasd  qwe  qweqwe
```

Comment: Yes they're characters, but not the tab character \t which I have specified as delimiter :) Don't want to use printf to specify length, want to create columns with `column`

Comment: @NiklasBerglund yes but there's no point in using the tab since your `column` command removes it.

Comment: @NiklasBerglund also see updated answer. You can add the colors after using column and avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use `column` because some columns are of dynamic width. Nice idea to add colors after using `column` 

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the next version v2.40 of [util-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) / [column](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) will handle text containing [Fe Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences) from [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) properly.

With [this change](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/2767), programs that output text with ANSI sequences will be handled correctly as in this example:

```shellsession
$ tput cols
108

$ echo BEFORE; ls -1 --sort=time --color=always | head -n 19 | column
BEFORE
column-test.sh  test_enosys             test_pathnames
column-pr.md                    test_mkfds              test_sha1
tests                   test_uuid_namespace     lib
ansiescape-test.txt             test_tiocsti            test_md5
column                  test_sigreceive         test_byteswap
text-utils              test_sysinfo
column-old.c                    test_strerror

$ echo REFERENCE; ls -1 --sort=time --color=never | head -n 19 | column
REFERENCE
column-test.sh          text-utils              test_tiocsti            test_sha1
column-pr.md            column-old.c            test_sigreceive         lib
tests                   test_enosys             test_sysinfo            test_md5
ansiescape-test.txt     test_mkfds              test_strerror           test_byteswap
column                  test_uuid_namespace     test_pathnames

$ echo AFTER; ls -1 --sort=time --color=always | head -n 19 | column
AFTER
column-test.sh          text-utils              test_tiocsti            test_sha1
column-pr.md            column-old.c            test_sigreceive         lib
tests                   test_enosys             test_sysinfo            test_md5
ansiescape-test.txt     test_mkfds              test_strerror           test_byteswap
column                  test_uuid_namespace     test_pathnames
```