# the output of “column” is misaligned when the text is colored

Tags: colors, columns

I have a list of sentences in a tcsh script, which are separated by '\n' and may have white spaces inside. I want to show them in the style of ls, so I did "echo $list| column". it works fine when there is no color used. the result is as below
[image: the desired format, when no color is used.]

Then I need to highlight some items which are changed(latest 3 choices) each time to show up. I add the color sequences (\e[33m and \e[0m) around the items I want to highlight, and still put them into the $list. 
When I show them with "echo $list | column", the color is ok, but the text are misaligned as following picture.[image: misaligned after add color]

Note, I tried that if not use '| column', the strings showed correctly in one column, even though not the style I want.

Is there is some solution for the problem?

BTW, I did some search and it seems to be a bug of column. Is there any maintainer for column? Where should I report the issue?

NOTE: I've read [Issue with column command and color escape codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251751/issue-with-column-command-and-color-escape-codes) before the post. His format is fixed, while mine to be colored items are dynamic. So simply use printf or add color after column can not work

Comment: I read that before, but his format is fixed, while mine to be colored items are dynamic. So simply use printf or add color after column can not work

Comment: You can still add color after `column`. I've added an answer demonstrating this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape sequences that colorize output are not understood by `column`, which operates by merely counting “printable characters” in its input.  As an example, the sequence to turn text green (`^[[0;32m`) contains six printable characters, and will count as such.

If you want to see what `column` really sees when it determines column width, try something like this:

```
ls --color=always / | tr -dc '\n -~' | column -s '\n'
```

Replace `ls --color=always /` with any command that has colored output if your `ls` does not support this option.

There is no way to convince `column` to ignore these escape sequences, but you can instead add the color afterward.

Say you have a file `to-list` that looks like this:

```
1: avifsc01
2: avifsh01_bg4dtva0f
3: avifsh01_bg5dtvz1f
4: bg2ctqz1
5: bg2dtva0
6: bg3cda0
7: bg3cda1
8: bg3cdpa0
9: bg3z1
10: bg4cdpa0f
11: bg4cdpz1f
12: bg4cdz1f
13: bg4cta0f
14: bg4ctpa0f
15: bg4ctpz1f
16: bg4ctz1f
17: bg4dtva0f
18: bg4dtvz1f
19: bg5ctpz1f
20: bg5ctz1f
21: bg5dtvz1f
22: bg6ctz1f
23: bgpk01
24: dsc
25: test
26: vpp01
27: vrdlib01
```

Then you do:

```sh
list=$(cat to-list)
```

And suppose you know you want to color a few specific entries:

```sh
to_color='bg3cda0 bg4dtva0f bg6ctz1f'
```

You can format the list with `column` before colorizing it:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${list}"                         \
| column -s '\n'                                \
| sed "s@$( (printf '%s\\|' ${to_color}; echo)  \
            | sed 's@^@\\([0-9][0-9]*: \\(@'    \
            | sed 's@\\|$@\\)\\)@'              \
       )@$(printf '\033')[33m\1$(printf '\033')[0m@g"
```

These entries can be dynamically generated so long as you have some way to generate these two variables (`${list}` and `${to_color}`).

The result:

[image: colorized output]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the help. By the way, I can not make the (printf '\033') work in tcsh, and failed to find a equivalent, do you know?

Comment: @AlexC I didn't realize you were using `tcsh`.  I don't have `tcsh` on any of my systems, but `csh` exists.  Try Ctrl+v Esc in place of `$(printf '\033')` — that's just how I usually insert a literal escape character in things.

Comment: Starting with the next version v2.40 of [util-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) / [column](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) will handle text containing [Fe Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences) from [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) properly.

With [this change](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/2767), programs that output text with ANSI sequences will be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The colorizing sequences are messing up the character count for `column` so you can add color
after the columnizing step , as in:

```
set items2color = ( "bg3cda0" "bg4dtva0f" "bg6ctz1f" )
echo "$list" | column |\
perl -slpe '\
   for my $c ( split /\s+/, $C ) {\
      s/(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\t))\d+:\s+\Q$c\E(?=\t|$)/\e[31m$&\e[0m/;\
   }\
' -- -C="$items2color"
```

The particular items that you wanted colorized, are placed on the command line in the option `-C`, you may change any name though,
which then is available to Perl via the $C variable. Since it is a space-separated list of items, we
split it up on spaces and apply the regex on the current line.
The backslashes at the end of lines are for the `tcsh` since you said it's a `tcsh` list variable you were operating on.

## Regex

A brief working of the regex is in order and given below:
Note that since the regex is not attached to any variable, it means it attaches to the $_ variable, which is the current line in our case.

```
/
   (?:             # From where we are,
      (?<=^)       # we see the beginning of the current line to our left
         |         # OR
      (?<=\t)      # we see a TAB to our left
   )
          # We are the beginning of a digit

  \d+:    # followed by one or more digits, ending in a colon
  \s+     # then atleast one whitespace
  \Q$c\E  # followed by the item to be colored. \Q...\E quote the $c should
          # it comprise any characters which mean something to the regex.

 (?= \t | $ ) # we see a TAB or the end of line to our right
/x;
```

Comment: But did the solution given to you worked or not?

Comment: I don't know why your regex not work. I modified it to s/\d+: \b($c)\b/\e[33m$&\e[0m/ and it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: The issue is due to the fact that there are some list entries that have whitespace. `(?=\t|$)` ---> `(?=\s*\t|$)`