Colored output from fd piped into column not aligned correctly
When I run the command fd --color always --max-depth=1 | column the output is not properly aligned, but it is when --color is set to --color never
For reference, fd --color never --max-depth=1 | column prints
test-folder/    test12.txt  test16.txt  test2.txt   test5.txt   test9.txt
test1.txt   test13.txt  test17.txt  test20.txt  test6.txt
test10.txt  test14.txt  test18.txt  test3.txt   test7.txt
test11.txt  test15.txt  test19.txt  test4.txt   test8.txt

(It is properly aligned on my terminal, not sure why copy and pasting it here makes it look not aligned?)
And fd --color always --max-depth=1 | column prints
test-folder/    test19.txt
test1.txt           test2.txt
test10.txt          test20.txt
test11.txt          test3.txt
test12.txt          test4.txt
test13.txt          test5.txt
test14.txt          test6.txt
test15.txt          test7.txt
test16.txt          test8.txt
test17.txt          test9.txt
test18.txt

I'm finding that the rows that aren't properly aligned are the ones with different colors. All the .txt files are green, while the folder is blue.The first row is not aligned because there are two items of different colors (a blue folder and a green txt file).
According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769660 version 2.40 of column should properly handle color codes; my column version from the man page is:
util-linux 2.40.2   2024-07-04    COLUMN(1)
What's a simple way to have output from fd output in a bunch of columns? My use case is that I'd prefer to be using fd instead of ls every time I want to look at the files in a directory.

Similar: A shell tool to “tablify” input data containing ANSI escape codes

According to the git changelog of util-linux, color escape sequence support in column didn't make it into the 2.40 series (nor the 2.41-devel tag). Apparently it'll appear in 2.41 or even 2.42, I'm not sure. It is already there in the master branch, you might want to give that a try.
